# Python Pymongo auth failed

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Pymongo keep failing to login MongoDB. I typed right password for "root" account.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apis import app
  File "/home/app/apis/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import apis.call
  File "/home/app/apis/call.py", line 12, in <module>
    import auth
  File "/home/app/apis/auth.py", line 18, in <module>
    connection.api.authenticate(database.ADMIN_ID,database.ADMIN_PASSWD)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 875, in authenticate
    self.connection._cache_credentials(self.name, credentials)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 456, in _cache_credentials
    auth.authenticate(credentials, sock_info, self.__simple_command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 243, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials[1:], sock_info, cmd_func)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 222, in _authenticate_mongo_cr
    cmd_func(sock_info, source, query)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 687, in __simple_command
    helpers._check_command_response(response, None, msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 178, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'root'), ('nonce', u'9e44852e6597a1de'), ('key', u'f132369d21874c9858409e235abff25f')]) failed: auth failed
```

Here is pymongo

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("127.0.0.1")
connection.api.authenticate("root","1234")
db = connection.api
```

does pymongo use md5 on password? it looks like there is some different password in mongodb data.

here is mongodb admin system.users data

{
  "user": "root",
  "pwd": "cde0d84e6749c235a3b4e36d945eb6fe",
  "roles": [
    "userAdminAnyDatabase"
  ]
}

Do you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to connect table called api.

```
connection.api.authenticate("root","1234")
```

There wasn't admin account in api table. I did put in system.admin table. So, I created a new admin account in api table and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I upgraded pymongo

```
pip install --upgrade pymongo
```

Comment: Upgrading leads to following error:     ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
False is not a read preference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to cut the certificate from the Bluemix MongoDB Credentials, save in a file (e.g. certificate.pem), and refer to it as follows:

`client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri_string, ssl_ca_certs='c:\data\certificate.pem')`