# Authentication failed to connect to mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

We have written a piece of code in python script using `pymongo` that connects to mongodb.

```
username = 'abc'
password = 'xxxxxx'
server = 'dns name of that server'
port = 27017
```

In program, the code looks like:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(url, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=300)
database = client.database_name
data_insert = database.collection_name.insert_one({'id': 1, 'name': xyz})
```

When I tried to do these operations, it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1114, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1036, in _refresh
    self.__collation))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 873, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 905, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 916, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 168, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 792, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 512, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 470, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 450, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 201, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

In MongoDB, while performing queries we are getting the responses normally, without raising any errors.

Comment: try connecting with the mongo server manually using the same credentials, you may use mongo shell for that.

Comment: @Shashank I can connect manually to mongo server with the same credentials, but my goal is to connect to mongo using `pymongo`

Comment: Have you tried these solutions: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346767/pymongo-auth-failed-in-python-script
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200288/mongolab-pymongo-connection-error
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682933/python-pymongo-auth-failed

Comment: Try adding `/your-db-name` to the `host`, that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Because the other answers to your question didn't work for me, I'm going to copy and paste my answer from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703050/13507510).

If you've tried the above answers and you're still getting an error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

There's a good chance you need to add `?authSource=admin` to the end of your uri.

Here's a working solution that I'm using with MongoDB server version 4.2.6 and MongoDB shell version v3.6.9.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Replace these with your server details
MONGO_HOST = "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX" 
MONGO_PORT = "27017"
MONGO_DB = "database"
MONGO_USER = "admin"
MONGO_PASS = "pass"

uri = "mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?authSource=admin".format(MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASS, MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT, MONGO_DB)
client = MongoClient(uri)
```

Similar fix for command line is adding `--authenticationDatabase admin`

Comment: This worked for me connecting to MongoDB (AWS EC2) from a Flask instance (AWS ECS) on the same VPC with security inbound rules set for MongoDB to accept from the ECS security group.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I have been stuck with the same error for almost 3-4 hours. I came across solution with the following steps:

from your shell connect to MongoDB by typing: `mongo`

afterwards, create a database: `use test_database`

Now create a user with the following command with `readWrite` and `dbAdmin` privileges.

```
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "test_user",
     pwd: "testing12345",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
);
```

This will prompt `Successfully added user: { "user" : "test_user", "roles" : [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] }`

you can check by typing: `show users`.
It will also show you DB name you created before in the json.

now you should be able to insert data to your database:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://test_user:myuser123@localhost:27017/test_database")
db = client.test_database

data = {"initial_test":"testing"}
db["my_collection"].insert_one(data).inserted_id
```

Comment: An underrated answer. You solved my problem ! To give a bit of context: I am using Docker as container to create the service and connection with mongodb. I had to pull new changes form a github repo, re-configured dockercompose.yml. Then, I wanted to reconnect with same credentials I've done before and for some reason I had this issue. Apparently, for some reason, this reconfiguration deleted my previous user, and now I wanted to reconnect with same credentials and the user was not found. I created the user like you explained, and it worked like charm ! Thanks mate !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error, and my problem was with the password.

I had what I believe to be a special character in the Master account. Changing the password to be only alphanumeric fixed it for me.

Code snippet

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        'mongodb://username:alphaNumericPassword@localhost:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false'
    )

    # Specify the database to be used
    db = client['prod-db']
```